# Table view cells with dynamic height

Tags: ios, uitableview

I hope you can help me to solve this.

I have a Table View, the cells have an image and the height of the cell depends on the image. I use SDWebImage to manage the download of the images. To get the image I use this sentence in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
[cell.imageView func_crossdissolveFromURL:imageURL];
```

The function func_crossdissolveFromURL is the following:

```
- (void)func_crossdissolveFromURL:(NSString *)urlString {
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self.downloadOperation cancel];

    if (!urlString) {
        return;
    }

    UIImage *memImage = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromMemoryCacheForKey:urlString];
    if (memImage) {
        [self _crossdisolve:memImage cacheType:SDImageCacheTypeMemory];
        return;
    }

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    __weak UIImageView *wself = self;
    id<SDWebImageOperation> operation = [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                     options:SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates
                                                    progress:nil
                                                   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
                                                       [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                                       if (!wself) return;
                                                       dispatch_main_sync_safe(^{
                                                           if (!wself || !image) return;
                                                           [self _crossdisolve:image cacheType:cacheType];
                                                       });
                                                   }];
    self.downloadOperation = operation;
}
```

And the function called _crossdissolve called close to the end is this:

```
- (void)_crossdisolve:(UIImage *)image cacheType:(SDImageCacheType)cacheType {
    CGFloat duration = (cacheType == SDImageCacheTypeMemory) ? 0 : 0.25f;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                  duration:duration
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.image = image;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self setNeedsLayout];
                }];
}
```

So, how could I have each cell with the height of the content image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

1. Set the cell height to be automatic: `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`
2. Define the height of the cell using auto layout

To change the height of a cell after it has been displayed you can reload the cell.

Comment: It is not working for me, if I add  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;  and I don't use heightForRowAtIndexPath the result is the same. Maybe I am not doing well the step number 2, how to do it well?

Comment: Not sure about well, but you need to make sure at the very least, the height of the cell is defined unambiguously using your constraints. You might also want to add an estimated height (`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 87.0f;`).

Comment: Instead of it I have the function estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and there I return UITableViewAutomaticDimension but it doesn't work well

Comment: Your estimated height can't be automatic.

Comment: This is driving me crazy, I can't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: Maybe try documenting your problem better.